# contradiction in changing value of a two way data bidden form field

Tags: angular, two-way-binding

I am trying to make a form like this.

https://ibb.co/pyChmz4

Whenever i want to add a new item which is allowed to be edited later on, in an input form appears above, all the number of items are set to the same number as in the last one added. Although they are different as can be seen in json.

The code is as follows. 
"OrderItems" is supplied by the component.

Where am i doing wrong?

```
 <div class="h-100 v-100 border rounded" style="background-color:#FFEBEE">
        <p class="text-black-50 m-2 font-weight-bolder">items to be added</p>
        <div class="item-flex-container m-2 p-2" name="orderItemList" *ngFor="let orderitem of orderItems">

          <mat-form-field class="col-6">
            <mat-select placeholder="Item description" name="item" [(value)]="orderitem.item.id" (selectionChange)="changeItem(orderitem)">
              <mat-option *ngFor="let item of items" [value]="item.id" name="itemid">{{item.description}}</mat-option>
            </mat-select>
          </mat-form-field>
          <mat-form-field class="input-number">
          <input matInput placeholder="number of items" name="numberofItem" type="number" [(ngModel)]="orderitem.number">
          </mat-form-field>
          <div class="add-button">
            <a style="font-size: 15px; font-weight: 200;" color="warn" mat-mini-fab matTooltip="change"><i class="fa fa-ellipsis-v"
                aria-hidden="true"></i>
            </a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="item-flex-container m-2 mt-5">
        <mat-form-field class="col-6">
          <mat-select name="item" placeholder="Item description" [(ngModel)]="form.itemid">
            <mat-option *ngFor="let item of items" value="{{item.id}}" name="item">{{item.description}}</mat-option>
          </mat-select>
        </mat-form-field>
        <mat-form-field class="input-number">
          <input matInput placeholder="number of items" type="number" name="numberItemAdd" [(ngModel)]="form.numberItemAdd">
        </mat-form-field>
        <div class="add-button">
          <a style="font-size: 30px; font-weight: 500;" color="warn" (click)="add(form.itemid)" mat-mini-fab
            matTooltip="Add new Item">+
          </a>
        </div>
```

Comment: Can you build a *small* stackblitz example of your issue so we can better see it?

Comment: it is not very possible there are so many things. What i basicly try to do is; formfield => variable Array<=> another formfield